# How to find a stored website password when the browser shows no password was saved?

Tags: windows, firefox, passwords

My friend came today with strange issue.  He forgot his Facebook password. 
He can still log in to Facebook because the password is stored in the computer. I told him to look in the browser because he should be able to see the password there, but there was none. I personally checked and there really isn't any password stored in Firefox. But nevertheless, as soon as he gets on Facebook he gets logged in.

Anyone knows how we can see that password and where it might be stored ?

Comment: Seems your friend can reset their password as long as they are logged in; see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A browser does not need to save a password in order for a website to keep one logged in: after logging in to a website (Facebook), it sets a cookie with some id that tells the site that the browser is logged in. Whenever a page is requested from the website, the browser sends that cookie along, so no password is needed.

Some websites use cookies that are automatically removed when you close the browser, but a website could also make the cookie live for as long as it wants, even forever. If you would clear the cookies (don't do that!), the "[session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID)" would end, making the website prompt one for the credentials again.

So: it seems no password was saved in the browser at all; it's just that the browser still has the cookie that keeps your friend logged in.

(Luckily, even if you don't have a proper email address configured, Facebook offers [a way to reset it](https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate): *"If you're logged into Facebook on another device, we'll send you a notification to reset your password."*)

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't stated how you've looked for the password, [these instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import) show how to view your saved passwords:

- Click the `menu` button and choose `Options`.
- Click the `Security` panel.
- Click `Saved Passwords` and the Password Manager will open.
- To see the passwords you have saved, click `Show Passwords`. When you close the window, your passwords will be automatically hidden.

Comment: Hi Jonno.  This is the first thing I checked. And that is why its unclear to me how facebook logs in while there is no saved password in the browser ( saved passwords as you mentioned above).

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, sounds like you are trying to hack your friends password.

Firefox passwords are not secure anyway so you should not be using them.

My advice would be to install LASTPASS and have it import your firefox passwords, then when you go to a facebook site you will see all the logins for that site or you can just open your lastpass vault and type in facebook

Comment: Depends in which way you mean "hack" the passwords. If its stealing his password without him knowing about it, then no. :)     So lastpass should import the password although the password is not showing in firefox passwords ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, @DasGjinovskaLignja, LastPass will only import passwords that are indeed stored in a browser. If nothing has been stored, there's nothing to import either.